# .NET IIS Problem with Windows patch KB4576947

Tags: asp.net, iis

We are experiencing a problem with Windows Update (KB4576947), after this patch installation our .NET applications hosted on IIS have stopped working. We tried to create new application but that also did not work on IIS. All request are resulting in 500 and we are getting no logs either in IIS logs or in Event Viewer.

Please let me know if any other person faced the same issue? And how to resolve it? In our case we uninstalled the patch to run our .NET apps on IIS.

Comment: "Cumulative Update Preview" shouldn't be applied on a production machine. To report such issues though, you can contact Microsoft support via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: After updating the window system, incompatibility sometimes occurs. You can try to reinstall your iis. If the problem still cannot be solved, then I suggest you follow the Lex Li suggestion to ask for [support from Microsoft](https://support.serviceshub.microsoft.com/supportforbusiness/onboarding?origin=%2Fsupportforbusiness%2Fcreate).